# Real Time Capabilities?

Tags: clojure

Over the last few weeks I've been learning and experimenting with Clojure and Erlang. From what I understand both solve the same type of problems - but - with different approaches. If that is correct, then is Clojure just as viable an option for real-time systems like chat applications or ticker plants, as Erlang is?

Comment: Chat apps and ticker plants are soft realtime, which means any language will do.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

both address concurrent programming though in different environments:

- Clojure is really good at **shared memory concurrent programming**. Where there are many threads all working on a single big chunk of memory (the heap) and they need to coordinate access to shared objects within that memory.
- Erlang is really good at **share nothing distributed computing** where processes need to be able to run on many computers and work on independent memory spaces. They do not coordinate shared access to objects.

Both of these systems are "soft real time" and are well suited to things like chat and control systems though neither of them would be suited to system with hard real-time requirements.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. As a follow-up, from what I've read so far Erlang touts the fact that it's process (thread) management is NOT OS dependent thus somehow making it more efficient/effective. Do you have any experience with this?

Comment: Because of the ability to directly pipe functions over the network, erlang is really effective on heterogeneous networks, so long as you can do the job with message passing alone

Answer (score 7):

As far as [Clojure](http://clojure.org/) goes, it can provide as much real time capabilities as the underlying Java VirtualMachine can.

You *CAN* create a hard real time system with a JVM, but this has to go beyond just the language syntax that Clojure provides.

Depending on your real-time requirement, it looks like you are going to need to tune the JVM (here is a good [IBM Works article](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-rtj1/index.html) or to use a specific JVM like the [Fiji JVM](http://www.azimuth-corp.com/conference/S52010/papers/presentations/Day_3/Fiji%20VM%20-%20Safety%20Critical%20Java%20%5BPizlo%5D.pdf)

Concerning Erland, there is already a related [questions on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1569035/what-makes-erlang-suitable-for-soft-real-time-applications)

Chat and ticker plants applications can be achieved with both languages, but I personally suspect it would be easier to deploy with Clojure, especially looking at the offers in the Cloud ([Heroku](http://www.heroku.com/)) and regular hosting services.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, Clojure is a very viable option for (soft) real time applications.

You can basically get real time performance equivalent to anything else on the JVM. Since people use the JVM for realtime trading platforms (e.g [These guys](http://www.lmaxtrader.co.uk)) then I'm sure it will be fine for chat or stock tickers.

Clojure is particularly good for **highly concurrent applications that access shared state**, since it has a very nice [model of Software Transactional Memory](http://clojure.org/concurrent_programming) that scales especially well with large numbers of threads / large numbers of cores. I believe there is a video somewhere of Rich Hickey demonstrating a concurrent Clojure application on a 768-core Azul systems box without any issues.

You can contrast this with Erlang, which is designed for **highly distributed actors that do not share state**. This gives Erlang applications tremendous redundancy and scalability across clusters of machines, but each process gets to manage it's own independent state.